# Trying to find html code to format pasted text

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have extensive code that I am using to paste from Excel cells, ranges, and strings, etc. I can get certain things to format the way I need them to, but I cannot get certain strings to do so.

For Example:
I can get constant text to bold:

`"<b><u>Status:</u></b>"`

But I cannot get this string to do the same:

`& Cells(i, "B").Text &`

```
For i = 10 To 18 
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then 'Add to growing string
        concatString = concatString & Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & "<br>" & vbCr 
        concatString = concatString & "<b><u>Status:</u></b>" & " " & Cells(i, "C").Text & "<p>" & vbCr 
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing, just concatenating the variable into the string.

Like this:

```
"<b><u>" & Cells(i, "B").Text & "</u></b>"
```

**Updated:**

To add to the code you have included in your question (you did not really specify what you wanted bold and underlined... so I'll guess that you want all of it bold):

```
For i = 10 To 18 
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then 'Add to growing string
        concatString = concatString & "<b><u>" 
        concatString = concatString & Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & "<br>"
        concatString = concatString & "Status:" & " " & Cells(i, "C").Text
        concatString = concatString & "</u></b>"
    End If
Next i
```

That will make it all bold and underlined.

<sub>Note: **vbCr** does nothing inside of HTML, so I removed it.</sub>

If you want just that one line bold and underlined, do it like this:

```
For i = 10 To 18 
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then 'Add to growing string
        concatString = concatString & Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & "<br>"
        concatString = concatString & "<b><u>" 
        concatString = concatString & "Status:" & " " & Cells(i, "C").Text
        concatString = concatString & "</u></b>"
    End If
Next i
```

<sub>Notice I put the HTML tags on their own lines, so you can move them around more easily without having to edit the lines of the code which have the data.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help! But when I run it like this I get a "Compile error: Expected: end of statement" message, and "<b><u>" gets highlighted, then "B" gets highlighted if I change the "" on the HTML markers.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What i answered is not a complete statement. It's just showing you how to build a string. You did not include anything showing how you wanted to use it.

Comment: This is a workbook that a user inputs data into assigned cells, and then emails it out to a group.  But I am trying to paste CERTAIN data straight into the body of the email so the user can who is included at a glance, without opening the attachment. I have concatenated those lists, and am trying to make bold the pasted values from Column B in the sheet, and then highlight Column C, etc. I'm being as clear as mud, right?

Comment: ```For i = 10 To 18
    If Not Cells(i, "A").Text = vbNullString Then
         'Add to growing string
         concatString = concatString & Cells(i, "A").Text & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Text & "<br>" & vbCr
         concatString = concatString & "<b><u>Status:</u></b>" & " " & Cells(i, "C").Text & "<p>" & vbCr
    End If```

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments. As you can see it does not format properly. Instead, edit your question and include the code you are in need of help with.